# @WebMvcTest Found Status 404 And Service return null

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spock

When I use `@WebMvcTest` to test my Spring Controller, I meet two questions.

1. MockMvc can't find right URL
2. After I add `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()`, mockMvc was worked.But My Controller `throw NullPointException caused by @Autowired Service`

I just do unit-test, so I don't want to use `@SpringBootTest` to starup all my SpringBoot Aplication.
I have try to `@InjectMock` My Controller and `@Mock or @MockBean` Service.The are all didn't work.
So could someone tell me why `@Autowired` mockMvc can't find the Controller and how to mock inner `@Autowired`  filed in Spock unit test without `@SpringBootTest`?

Here are my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/schedule/filter")
public class ScheduleObjectFilterController extends BaseController {
    @PostMapping(path="/",produces  = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String createScheduleObjectFilter(@RequestBody String body){
        BaseResponse<ResponseStatus> resp = new BaseResponse<>(ResponseStatus._200);
        try{
            List<ScheduleObjectFilterParam> paramList = parseJSONArray(body,ScheduleObjectFilterParam.class);
            resp.setStatus(scheduleObjectFilterService.createScheduleObjectFilter(paramList));
        }catch(BaseRuntimeException e){
            logger.error("Create ScheduleObjectFilter error:", e);
            resp.setException(e);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Create ScheduleObjectFilter error:", e);
            resp.setStatus(ResponseStatus._500);
        }
         return renderJSON(resp);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ScheduleObjectFilterService scheduleObjectFilterService;

}
```

Here are my Service and it's implement

```
public interface ScheduleObjectFilterService{
     ResponseStatus createScheduleObjectFilter(List<ScheduleObjectFilterParam> paramList);
}
```

```
@Service
public class ScheduleObjectFilterServiceImpl extends BaseService implements ScheduleObjectFilterService {
    public ResponseStatus createScheduleObjectFilter(List<ScheduleObjectFilterParam> paramList) {
    // some code
    }
}
```

Here is my test class

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [ScheduleObjectFilterController.class])
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class ScheduleSettingControllerSpecification extends Specification{

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc

    @MockBean
    BaseController baseController

    @MockBean
    ScheduleObjectFilterService scheduleObjectFilterService

    def setup(){
        //after add next line,the mockMvc can find url,but service throw NullPointException
        //mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new ScheduleObjectFilterController()).build()
        scheduleObjectFilterService.createScheduleObjectFilter(_ as List) >> ResponseStatus._500
    }

    def "MvcTest"(){
        given:
        ScheduleObjectFilterParam param = new ScheduleObjectFilterParam()
        List<ScheduleObjectFilterParam> dataList = Collections.singletonList(param)
        expect:
        mockMvc.perform(post("/schedule/filter/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(JSONObject.toJSONString(dataList)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
    }

}
```

before add `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()`:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /schedule/filter/
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

After add That:

```
2019-11-10 11:53:22.896 [WEB] [ERROR] com.kaifa.hes.schedule.controller.ScheduleObjectFilterController.createScheduleObjectFilter() -> Create ScheduleObjectFilter error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.kaifa.hes.schedule.controller.ScheduleObjectFilterController.createScheduleObjectFilter(ScheduleObjectFilterController.java:47) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
......
```

this exception direct to this line in controller

```
resp.setStatus(scheduleObjectFilterService.createScheduleObjectFilter(paramList));
```

Comment: You have to add mock the service also, add `@MockBean` on `scheduleObjectFilterService`. `@WebMvcTest` is only to test th web layer like controller

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I added it before, but it still throw NullPointException

Answer (score 2):

`@WebMvcTest` is only used to test the web layer by application, so you need to mock any dependencies in controller and stub the method call. [more information](https://www.baeldung.com/injecting-mocks-in-spring)

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [ScheduleObjectFilterController.class])
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class ScheduleSettingControllerSpecification extends Specification{

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc

@MockBean
BaseController baseController

@MockBean
ScheduleObjectFilterService  scheduleObjectFilterService


def "MvcTest"(){

    when(this.scheduleObjectFilterService.createScheduleObjectFilter(ArgumentMatchers.anyList())
     .thenReturn(// custom error);    

    given:
    ScheduleObjectFilterParam param = new ScheduleObjectFilterParam()
    List<ScheduleObjectFilterParam> dataList = Collections.singletonList(param)
    expect:mockMvc.perform(post("/schedule/filter/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(JSONObject.toJSONString(dataList)))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I added it before, but it still throw NullPointException

Comment: ok,I have done it.However, in some blogs I read, def obj = Mock(SomeClass) in Spock seem to do the same like @MockBean SomeClass someClass. I don't know if I really understand the relationship between them.

Comment: you should also stub the method on mocked object by using `when` or `given` @New_Code

Comment: Thank you. I have been known the real reason that cause NullPointException. Spock don't support the @InjectMocks Annotation.So if I want to use the same function, I should use the third-party Spock extension likes https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spock-subjects-collaborators-extension

Answer (score 0):

@InjectMocks can't work in Spock. If we want to use the same function,here has a  [third-part extension](https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spock-subjects-collaborators-extension#collaborator-injection-to-subjects)
We can use the @Subject and @Collaborator annotation to solve this problem.
**Pay attention**,Spock has its own @Subject annotation.Before import the package,please check if it in correct packages